# Nodejs for api calls

Tags: php, api, node.js

Currently I have a php script that external sites access with a api key. Based on the api key it returns data back in json. I been reading up on nodejs and feel this might be a good use of nodejs since I have noticed a high load/access of the api, though Im still new at this so might be wrong if I am wrong let me know. My question is in my php script I do a lot of checks to determine what information to pass back, using nodejs should I be doing all the checks using javascript or can I still use php with nodejs to extract the information needed to pass back as json?

**EDIT**

the PHP script/API consists of mysql access if that helps at all

Comment: Your host has to support node.js (i.e. have it installed), which is not very common.

Comment: We have a dedicated box. So I have 100% access to the server.

Comment: Node.js == One of the better reasons to make the move away from shared hosting.

Comment: @John you have to re-write the logic in JS. Theres no way to proxy through PHP without creating a bottle neck unless you write a PHP interpreter that runs on node.js

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to create a problem for node.js to solve. Just because there's high access to an API doesn't mean it's suited to node. If there's an actual performance bottleneck, take a look at optimising the PHP first.

Comment: @box9 The issue isnt php its the amount of times the api is accessed. If it was php I would be looking at db optimization, better php code rather than nodejs. The api gets accessed so much we get a high load on the server, unless I can limit the connection using php I thought with nodejs ability to accept requests and keep on going to the next it would make things faster. Maybe Im wrong, that is why Im posting on here.

Comment: @Raynos I figured as such. I was planning to use the mysql module nodejs has for the db query then loop through the results and put it all in json and send it back to the client. Do you know of any tutorials on how to loop through the rows and dynamically build json and pass back using nodejs? Or perhaps modules to use for that? They would then access it as such mysite.com:port/apitype/action/apikey

Comment: @Box9 the alternative would be file based caching or memcache. Again because it was the amount of connections to the api I thought nodejs would be a good answer.

Comment: @John how many connections are you receiving per second? It is true that node.js can handle much larger numbers of concurrent connections that most servers, but many wrongly take this to mean an increase in performance (or decrease in server load).

Comment: @Box9 Yeah I guess what I meant is handling it better, I understand it still needs to do other things in the backend that can still bottleneck it. Looking around 30-50 per second (This is a guestimate). I have asked the external sites to throttle back with caching on their side which has helped. Our provider has even banned ips for excessive access.

Comment: Node.js is fit not just because of the speed, but also because JSON is it's native language.  https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql returns queries as javascript objects.

Returning them JSON is as simple as `res.end(JSON.stringify(result));`

Comment: @generalhenry another reason why I thought it was a good fit for this particular use. That and the less overhead I/O wise. So it can just sit there, listen on its own port, process requests after requests with no issues and spit it back up when done while its working on another process at the same time. Just seemed like a good fit. The only extra thing I would want it to do is cache the json value so that it wont have to hit the db everytime since the information does not change frequently.

Comment: Caching inside the node.js process is fairly easy since it persists.  `if(apitype.action.cache){res.send(apitype.action.cache)}else{queryDB(...)}`.

Comment: @John Switching Apache out for nginx can solve some of your problems in terms of load. But node only really shines if your dealing with long lived connections or > 400 connps. I'm all for switching to node though. Just do it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to memcache you can cache inside the Node.js process.

```
app.get('/:apitype/:action/:apikey', function( req, res ) {
  if( checkApiKey(req.params.apikey) === false ) {
    return res.send('Invalid API key');    
  }
  if( api[req.params.apitype][req.params.action].cache ) {
    return res.send( api[req.params.apitype][req.params.action].cache );
  }
  query( req.params.apitype, req.params.action, function ( result ) {
    api[req.params.apitype][req.params.action].cache = JSON.stringify(result);
    res.send( api[req.params.apitype][req.params.action].cache );
    setTimeout( function () {
      api[req.params.apitype][req.params.action].cache = null;           
    }, 5 * 60 * 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: @generalhenry Isnt that express? Or can you do the samething in nodejs as the code above? Express uses nodejs I understand that, just the code looks like its with express.

Comment: That's with express.js to help with the routing, you could use a regex to do the same thing, but express makes it easy.

Comment: @generalhenry What is the SetTimeout function for?

Comment: @generalhenry So correct me if Im wrong your script basically runs the global function checkApiKey against the api key passed via the url, if not valid send back invalid api key, otherwise check the global variable api array to see if there is cache set for this action, if so return the cache. otherwise run the query function and assign the cache variable to the json result and send it back to the client, then set the SetTimeout to clearcache in the futue? Is query a global function that runs nodejs module that queries the db and returns the results?

Comment: Exactly right. It assumes you've written your authentication logic into checkApiKey and query logic into query.

Comment: @generalhenry Got it, thanks! One other question, if I wanted to use this with long polling would I create a http server on a different port using express with the code above and on the client side create a jquery ajax request that would create a function to make a request to the nodejs server and inside the jquery function just call the same function again? So it loops over and over? Is that waht long polling is or would I need to do something else with the server side code with expression?

Comment: For long polling et al it's best to use `socket.io`.  It allows you to emit events and have those events sent by websockets, flashsockets, long polling etc . . . depending on the browse, without even needing a different port. (socket.io is the url)

Comment: @generalhenry So with socket.io I dont even need to set a timer do I? I just can set my action by the event correct? So I could emit an event on the server side called Update API then on the server side when the client invokes the Update API event I can still do everything I need to do such as query the db and return results? I appreciate the help!

Comment: And with socket.io returning the results is even easier, it auto JSON stringifies/parses so you can simply emit JSON, from client to server, server to client, client to client, all push.  The downside is that it would require a client side code rewrite to use, but since it makes your work easy and the upsides are huge I think it's at least worth prototyping.

Comment: @generalhenry Would I have to loop the function on the client side? So if I ran the api script above would I need to access the socket.io server from the client side and run it say every 5 seconds? Or does socket.io do that automatically?

Comment: socket.io abstractions all the polling, you just need to handle the events (emitters and handlers).

Comment: @generalhenry I guess thats where Im confused. Normally I have to use setInterval or something like that with jquery/ajax to have it run a script every n seconds. Is socket.io setup to only send data back to the client when new data is available without telling it on the server or client side to run every n seconds?

Comment: When possible it uses web sockets, which like normal sockets are a persistent connections that allow for efficient message pushing.  When they're not available socket.io falls back to long polling, but still interacts as if you where using web sockets. So on the server you can use `function newDataReady ( data ) {  sockets.emit('data update', data); }` and on the client `socket.on('data update',function ( data ) { . . . }` which would push to all the clients when your new data is ready.

Comment: @generalhenry Ok Im almost there understanding this, whats mentally blocking me is how does the server socket.io script know when to query the db for new data? I want to check the db for any new data and then push to the client. So how does it know to query the db on the server side, detect there are changes then push to client? I believe I understand the code you gave me above just cant wrap my head around how the server would know to send updated information without telling the server to refresh every n seconds.

Comment: mysql doesn't push so you'd need to poll it for changes, you could set up a setInterval on the server to check the DB and push to the clients if there's a change.   So polling on the server, and push to the client, which should reduce the load on the server since you wouldn't need to have each client poll the DB.

Comment: If the api is also filling up the DB you can have any of the add calls trigger change pushes as well.

Comment: @generalhenry If I did a setinterval on the server to poll the db every couple of seconds wouldnt that cause a resource issue? Especially if I dont use caching?

Comment: depends on the poll interval, and the query used, since you just need to know if its updated you can query just the last row and compare it, loading the rest only when needed.  And you can still cache in the node process.

Comment: @generalhenry Well I was thinking about using this for another web app I currently use which uses jquery and ajax to run a php script every 30 seconds. Sounds like socket.io would be a good replacement, just dont know if I polled the server say every couple of seconds if it would eat up a lot of resources.

Comment: I sounds like what you really want is a pub/sub system using mysql as a buffer.  If that's the case you just need to capture the events that add to the DB and have socket.io announce them along with the updated data.  That way you only need to query the DB when a new client connects, and even then you should be able to pull out of a cache most the time.

Comment: polling for "are there any events" every couple seconds is a low load, it's polling for "what's the state of the db" every couple seconds that would eat up resources.

Comment: @generalhenry Yeah that is where I felt the bottleneck would be for nodejs, socket.io. It can handle tons of connections etc but if your using a db like mysql you still are hobbled by the limitations of querying a db. If you had thousands of connections at once that polled the db then its still slow because of the db access, at least that is what Im thinking. Im still new to do this javascript server stuff so might be wrong.

Comment: One big mindshift is that Node.js is a single process, everyone shares the same thread, thousands of connections all with the same thread.  So instead of each user polling the DB it makes more sense to the Node.js process poll the DB and just update the users when things change.  So 1 poll loop per api instead of 1 poll loop per api per user.  Additional users of the same api have no impact on the DB that way.

Comment: @generalhenry But how does that work when you need to query a db based on the user logged in? So say there are 30 accounts, each account has different data assigned to them via mysql db. So you would need to query 30 different times wouldnt you to query the db for each specific user?

Comment: Assuming they are all querying the same table, you'd just need to poll the one table for changes (looking just at the last row) and only do full queries and full downloads on changes.  The biggest issue you have now is users are doing the polling on the client side, doing full queries and downloads with each poll.

Comment: @generalhenry Yeah its all the same table but I dont want to broadcast the return results, I don't want each user seeing each others information. I want to confine them to their own data. So if there is an update for user1 I only want to send the updated information to user1 not user2 and so on.

Comment: You want frequently poll for changes, when changes happen you want to push the changed data only to the users who's data has changed.  To pull it off you just need to have users logged in so you know who to push the data to.  Something like http://codr.cc/66350d/js

Comment: @generalhenry Wow thanks for the example! On a side note I was looking at a pub/sub system, one that seemed like a good one was called faye.

Comment: I haven't play around with pub/sub in Node.js, so I'll have to defer that question to others (other than to say I've heard only good things about faye)

Comment: @generalhenry Yeah I was just browsing since you mentioned pub/sub and that is what I came across. You been a huge help in understanding this. I have been eager to get going to play around with this stuff, just been building out my office and need to setup my dev server with linux so I can put this all to the test.

Comment: Check out http://cloud9ide.com/ you can run your dev server from there.  With there great ide.  It runs git and npm in the console and will run node.js files and even make them publicly accessible from one port.  All free for now.

Comment: @generalhenry I will check it out, thanks! I wanted a dev box so I can learn to install this stuff as I will have a production box that I will need to install it on. Rather fudge up on dev than prod.

Answer (score 1):

Well it sounds like nodejs would not be the route to go in this case. I will instead go the route of either file based caching or memcache along with continue research to improve the code and db indexes/queries.

Comment: I don't know if this is an option or not, but have you heard of hiphop-php? https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php It's a PHP to C++ compiler written by facebook.  They claim to serve twice the content using 2/3 as much resources.  The wiki has an example of compiling and running wordpress.  I've never used it, but it may be worth looking into.

Comment: Sounds like a copout to me! You'll miss out on the joy of writing node.js ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am commenting on the first answer, but it is actually possible to run Node.js on a shared host as long as you have shell access or can compile and upload a compatible build of node. This method uses a library developed by samcday on github (http://github.com/samcday/node-fastcgi-application) and allows Node to respond to FastCGI calls. You do not need to be able to bind to a port on a public IP address and this will work with a virtual host.